# `TypeError: strptime() argument 0 must be str, not <class 'bytes'>`

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have this simple python program to plot a graph using matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime

days, impressions = np.loadtxt("page-impressions.csv", unpack=True,
        converters={ 0: mdates.strpdate2num('%Y-%m-%d')})

plt.plot_date(x=days, y=impressions, fmt="r-")
plt.title("Pageessions on example.com")
plt.ylabel("Page impressions")
plt.grid(True)

plt.savefig('test.pdf', format='pdf')
```

If I run this using `python3` it gives the following error.

`TypeError: strptime() argument 0 must be str, not <class 'bytes'>`

what am I doing wrong ?

b.t.w I have tried the suggestion `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117311/time-strptime-argument-0-must-be-str-not-bytes`
 doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: Have you tried the solution offered [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4126) ?

Answer (score 0):

The same problem in the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime

def datestr2num(s):
  return datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d").date().weekday()


# 读取CSV文件，设置分隔号，取元组第4，5字段，分拆存储不同列数据
d = np.loadtxt('AAPL_data.csv', delimiter=',', usecols=(0),converters={0 : datestr2num}, unpack=True)
```

Just change like this:

```
return datetime.datetime.strptime(s.decode("ASCII"), "%Y-%m-%d").date().weekday()
```